# Changing the ALLOWEDVALUES in tfs2010 to a AD group

Tags: workitem

I have a little problem with a work item.

My goal is to change the `<ALLOWEDVALUES>` of a work item to an AD group, so that not all "ValidUsers" can get a work item assigned. For this I've created a new TFS group "TFS_AssignGroup" and added the AD-group (AD-TFS_AssignGroup) to it.

Now I've changed the work item type definition:

```
<FIELD name="Assigned To" refname="System.AssignedTo" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" reportable="dimension">
        <HELPTEXT>The person currently working on this bug</HELPTEXT>
        <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true" filteritems="excludegroups">
            <LISTITEM value="[project]\TFS_AssignGroup" />
        </ALLOWEDVALUES>
      </FIELD>
```

Now I expected, that the AssignedTo-field only shows the people, who are in the AD-group. But it actually only shows me the AD-group itself. So I have exactly one entry in my AssignedTo-field: AD-TFS_AssignGroup.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that was an easy one: It just took some time to get the data from the AD. So the solution is to do nothing and wait (or restart the TFS server).